# Testing framework for ionic angular cordova app real devices with continuous integration?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, testing, ionic-framework

Our team is starting a project and we would like to have an automated testing server that tests our app on real devices, instead of emulators or just browser.

Its an Ionic framework app, so Cordova+AngularJS.

I am going to research this and give the best answer I have, but in the meantime if anyone is familiar with it, I'd love to hear all about it!

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested on that point too.

For instance, I manage to code very few tests with [APPIUM](http://appium.io/) but seems to do the job for tests using [Selenium webserver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Looking forward for other user feedback

Answer (score 0):

The intel xkd provides on device testing via the intel xkd preview app and on device debugging via the adb with debugger. Also comes with build services for android, ios, windows, tizen, amazon, nook, webapp, chrome, facebook, and firefox. This is the easiest way I have found for testing on device to make sure Cordova plug ins work and to get live JavaScript debugging. https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk

Comment: By live Javascript debugging do you mean continuous integration as in a server that runs a suite of tests whenever the master branch on github receives a push?

Comment: no as in you get a debugger on your computer you can see network and console logs while the app is running on the phone, only way to debug cordova plugins. If you want to automate testing (not on device) since it is an angular app you can always use protractor js, http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/using-the-protractor-automation-tool-to-test-angularjs-applications . if you are going to be using corodva plugins the intel xdk is the only way to really test it on a device without building and installing every time and still being able to debug

Comment: Hmmm interesting - this may have been a compelling option but we have already started building the app with other tools, namely ionic... 

I did a little bit of research and found this plugin - https://github.com/TadeasKriz/grunt-cordova-plugin-jasmine

Don't know just what it is yet, but if it works with Jenkins and offers testing on real devices, this would be perfect

Comment: well the intel xdk is really just like a hybrid app ide. I use it for developing ionic apps. I will check out the plugin, may come in handy. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to run the ionic app in phantomjs and run integration tests using your server-side framework. This allows you to quite easily test across the entire stack. Theres a blog post about how to do it with rails at http://www.dovetaildigital.io/blog/2015/10/28/rails-and-ionic-make-love-part-three